# Generate unique barcode for each registered user

Tags: users

I'm using D7 and I would like my website to create unique barcode for each user when they register an account, and send the barcode to them through email. This barcode should be part of their profile.

I found that "Barcode" module can generate barcode in a page, but I'm not sure how to use this module to create barcode for user. Is there any way I can modify the codes to do this?

Just some background information:

I need a barcode generated to each user as I want to scan it in mobile as taking attendance when web admin is having an event. After event ends, web admin will export the attendance list in excel or any document style, to check on the attendance detail (name, userid, date, scanned barcode)

Anyway the scanning and retrieving list is mobile app issue. I need to start with generating barcode first.

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

- Enable the barcode module.
- Goto: admin/config/people/accounts/fields
- Add a barcode field and configure as you like
- Towards the bottom of: admin/config/people/accounts, Modify the email to include the barcode

Another option: [Commerce Event Tickets](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_event_ticket), This sounds a lot like what you need.